# Retaining Nested Form Data Through Sign In Process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, nested-forms

I am using Devise with Rails 4.

When a user tries to submit a subarticle, which is nested in articles, they will be redirected to a sign up page if they don't already have an account. I have stored the form data to the users session so once they have signed up it can be submitted and saved to the data base.

I am having trouble also saving the articles title (the article in which the subarticle is being created under), so it can later be displayed in the users edit profile page. Everything else works fine, but when I call `<%= subarticle.article.title %>` I receive an error as it can't find article.

What would be the best way to save the article title with all of the subarticle form data?

Here is my code so far....

subarticles_controller.rb:

```
def create
    if current_user.nil?

     session[:subarticle] = params

     redirect_to new_user_registration_path

    else 

      @subarticle.user = current_user

      respond_to do |format|
        if @subarticle.save
          #1st argument of redirect_to is an array, in order to build the correct route to the nested resource comment
          format.html { redirect_to(@subarticle.article, :notice => 'Thank you for sharing your knowledge! Your subarticle is now undergoing review.') }
          format.mobile { redirect_to(@subarticle.article, :notice => 'Thank you for sharing your knowledge! Your subarticle is now undergoing review.') }
          #the key :location is associated to an array in order to build the correct route to the nested resource comment
          format.xml  { render :xml => @subarticle, :status => :created, :location => [@subarticle.article, @subarticle] }
        else
          format.html { render :action => "new" }
          format.mobile { render :action => "new" }
          format.xml  { render :xml => @subarticle.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

application_controller.rb:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if admin_signed_in? #Assuming there is such a function
      rails_admin_path
    elsif session[:subarticle].present?

      @subarticle = current_user.subarticles.create(session[:subarticle]["subarticle"])

      # clear session
      session[:subarticle] = nil

      #redirect
      flash[:notice] = "Awesome, you are logged in and your subarticle is undergoing review."      
      edit_user_registration_path
    else
      session[:previous_url] || root_path
    end
  end
```

Let me know if you need any further code. Thank you!